# ¿Por qué al momento de transformar un string a int y dividirlo el resultado contiene decimales?

Tags: python-3.x

Al momento de transformar el string a int, lo divido entre mil, por lo que el resultado debería ser `250000.777` pero al ser un int debería solo mostrarme los enteros ósea `250000`, a pesar de esto, en la consola me devuelve el valor con decimales ¿Por qué sucede? y ¿Cómo lo evito?

```
str_trama= str("250000777")

int_parte_entera= int(0)

int_parte_entera=int(str_trama)/1000

print(int_parte_entera)
```

Comment: Además de las soluciones planteadas abajo, quiero aclararte algo. No es necesario que hagas apliques la funcion str a "250000777". Cuando pones algo entre comillas Python ya lo interpreta como una cadena. Convertir una cadena en una cadena es innecesario (excepto que trates de convertir el contenido de una variable en cadena y el tipo de valor que tiene esa variable pueda variar)

Comment: Lo mismo aplica a int(0). Si pones un numero no decimal sin ponerle comillas alrededor, Python lo interpreta como un entero. Estás convirtiendo un entero en un entero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos encontrarnos con algunas curiosidades al momento de usar los operadores aritméticos como lo es la división. Para este caso podemos tener 3 escenarios distintos (no operadores) y con distintos resultados cada uno.

### Dividiendo enteros con `/`

Al usar el operador `/` python hace una división flotante, es decir que el resultado será siempre dado como un número de punto flotante (`float`).

```py
a = 10
b = 2

print(a/b)
#resultado-> 5.0
```

Como vemos, sin importar que los números sean enteros (tipo `int`) el resultado es de tipo `float` ya que se ha usado el operador de división flotante.

### Dividiendo enteros con `//`

Para hacer operaciones entre enteros se puede usar la doble barra `//` que devuelve la entera y se ignora la parte decimal. Por ejemplo:

```py
a = 5
b = 2

print(a//b)
#resultado-> 2
```

### Dividiendo números con `//`

Como vemos el resultado anterior es un entero y no un `float` esto debido a que se ha usado la doble barra al operar entre enteros. Pero si tratamos de operar con un `float` el resultado será igualmente un `float`.

```py
a = 10
b = 2.0

print(a//b)
#resultado -> 2.0
```

En este caso Python no puede retornar un entero dado que un valor es de tipo `float` y esto pasará en cualquier lenguaje. Una operación entre un número de punto flotante devuelve un número de punto flotante.

Si deseas tener siempre un entero sin importar los valores con los que operes es mejor que uses la clase `int` que hace la transformación a un valor entero, por defecto lo hace en base 10 (decimal) pero también se lo puedes especificar `int(num, base)`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que, estas transformando a `int` el dividendo, cuando deberías transformar a `int` el resultado de la división. Cómo evitarlo?, pues transformando a `int` la variable `int_parte_entera`.

La solución podría ser:

```
str_trama= str("250000777")

int_parte_entera=int(str_trama)/1000

print(int(int_parte_entera))
```

> 250000